# How to make a dynamic dropdown with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm new to JQuery, I'm using PHP in my code. I don't know how to make a dynamic dropdown. When user chooses from the first dropdown - region, next he to choose from onother dropdown - school, which is in this region. Please help!
My code is:

```html
<html>
<head>
 
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
  echo form_open();
  
  echo "<table border = '0' >";
  echo "<tr><td>  Region:*  </td><td>";
 echo "<select name = 'region[]' id='region' >";
  foreach($regions as $row) 
  {
    echo '<option value= "'.$row->region.'">'.$row->region.'</option>';
  } 
  echo "</select>";
  
  
   echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "<tr><td>  School:*  </td><td>";
  
  echo "<select name = 'school[]'  id='school'>";

  foreach($school_show as $row) 
  {
    echo '<option value="'.$row->school_name.'">'.$row->school_name.'</option>";
  } 
  echo "</select>";
  
  echo "</td></tr>";
echo form_submit($data);
  echo "</form>";
  echo "</table>";
```

Controller is:

```html
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {
public function register()
    {
$this->load->model('user_model');   
                $data['dynamic_view'] = 'register_form'; 
                $data['regions'] = $this->user_model->regions_show();
                $data['school_show'] = $this->user_model->school_show();
                $this->load->view('templates/main',$data);
            }   
}
```

Model is:

```html
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    
    public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('array');
         
    }
     
public function regions_show() {
        $this->db->select('region');
        $this->db->distinct('region'); 
        $this->db->from('schools');  

        $result=$this->db->get();
              return $result->result();

    }
    public function school_show() {
        $this->db->select('school_name'); 
       
        $this->db->from('schools');  

        $result=$this->db->get();
              return $result->result();

    }
}
```

Comment: When user selects a region in the first dropdown, you want to read the name of that region using `$(this).val()`. Then send this value with an ajax call to a PHP file, that will read all the schools from that region in the database, and send the list back to jQuery (typically in JSON format). Then, iterate this json and construct / update the second dropdown. There are thousands of tutorials about this around.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. I tried something from a tutorial, but as I don't know jQuery, I did't do it. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a java-script function with the first drop-down's onChange property. So, when the first drop-down value is selected it will call and pass the value to the function which will then be used to populate the second drop-down.

A simple example of the idea can be as follows -

```js
function populateSecond(id)
{
  if(id == 1){
    $('select[name=first]').append('<option value="a">A</option>');    
  }else{
    $('select[name=first]').append('<option value="b">B</option>');    
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="first" onChange="populateSecond(this.value);">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>  
</select>

<select name="second">
</select>
```